# explanation of MCMC and bayesian estimation

Tags: self-study

I have some questions about bayesian methods.

First of all I have a set of iid observations, calling $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ that come from a certain distribution $f$ with unknown parameters(for example Normal distribution). Then I can form likelihood by $P(D|\vec{\theta})=\prod_i^n f(y_i)$. Now I am going to use bayesian inference to estimate unknown parameters of posterior.

My questions are,

- How to choose prior?
- Given a prior (for example a gamma distribution) how can I estimate parameters?

Let denote parameters and data by $\theta=(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_p)$, $D=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ respectively. As far as I realize the posterior is

$$
Pos(\theta|D)\propto P(\theta)P(D|\theta)
$$

Because $\theta$ is unknown, how can I compute $P(\theta)$ and $P(D|\theta)$?

I would be very thankful If somebody give me an explanation of MCMC and connection to above paragraphs.

I want to appreciate all of you for your help: I also found a nice tutorial for bayesian and MCMC algorithm here :https://theoreticalecology.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/metropolis-hastings-mcmc-in-r/

Comment: I am closing this question as "too broad" since there is a clear lack of basic understanding of Bayesian statistics. For self-study questions, I think it's important that you demonstrate some level of autodidactic ability. Your questions are covered in virtually any text or online primer on the subject. It's important for this forum that you ask more refined questions, so I would refer you to [virtually any online materials from a reputable source](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I sympathize with your struggle because I was formally trained frequentist and had to pick up a lot of the Bayesian material on my own.  What you should realize is that unlike the frequentist approach, the Bayesian approach does not produce point estimates for model parameters but rather a distribution for them conditional on the data.  That is the posterior distribution $\theta|D \sim Pos(\theta\,|\,D)$ using your notation.  So where we would ordinarily have standard errors that approach zero asymptotically as the number of observations increases, we instead have a posterior distribution who's tails will get thinner and thinner as the number of observations increase, converging on single values asymptotically.

When it comes to actually doing Bayesian inference, MCMC is the most popular tool.  This is because MCMC can produce a sample from the posterior even when the mathematical form for the posterior is not known (which is the case when one is using non-conjugate priors).  In other words for $G$ iterations of MCMC we can simulate $\theta^{(1)},\theta^{(2)},...\theta^{(G)} \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Pos(\theta\,|\,D)$.  This posterior sample can then be used to calculate the probability of any hypothesis, i.e. $Pr(\theta_1<0)$.

I will use the Metropolis algorithm to exemplify how MCMC works as this was how I came to understand it.  (Gibbs sampling is the other popular MCMC algorithm, and there are some others too).   To begin we must specify both the likelihood and the prior.  For this example say we are trying to gather information on the parameters of a variable we know is normally distributed, so the parameters, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the mean and variance respectively.  The likelihood can then be written as

$$
P(y_1...y_n|\theta_1,\theta_2)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(y_i|\theta_1,\theta_2)
$$
where $f(y_i \; | \; \theta_1, \theta_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2} } \; e^{ -\frac{(y_i-\theta_1)^2}{2\theta_2} }$

A prior must also be specified for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.  There are many different priors we can use, for this example assume $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ to be independent and that $\theta_1$ is distributed normal with a known mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and $\theta_2$ is distributed chi-squared with known degrees of freedom $k$.  So
$$\theta_1 \sim P_1(\theta_1) \equiv \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi} } \; e^{ -\frac{(\theta_1-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$ 
and
$$
\theta_2 \sim P_2(\theta_2) \equiv \begin{cases} \frac{\theta_2^{(k/2-1)} e^{-\theta_2/2}}{2^{k/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)},  &if\;\; \theta_2 \geq 0; \\ 0, &if\;\; \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

There is nothing entirely special about these priors, other than my needing to choose something for this example.  In research, priors should always be developed in a thoughtful manner.

We can then write the posterior as being proportional to the product of the likelihood and prior, although I will use different notation here then you did in your question
$$
P(\theta_1,\theta_2|y_1...y_n) \propto P(y_1...y_n|\theta_1,\theta_2)P(\theta_1,\theta_2)=P(y_1...y_n|\theta_1,\theta_2)P_1(\theta_1)P_2(\theta_2)
$$
For ease of notation, define $\boldsymbol{\theta}=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$.
Notice that if I get values for $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ I can plug them into the likelihood and priors to get a value for $P(y_1...y_n|\boldsymbol{\theta})P(\boldsymbol{\theta})$

For the Metropolis algorithm, we must define yet another distribution $J(\boldsymbol{\theta}_i\,|\,\boldsymbol{\theta}_j)$ called a *jump* or *proposal* distribution where we can draw a parameter vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}_i$ conditional on a previous draw $\boldsymbol{\theta}_j$.  This distribution will usually be symmetric (for non-symmetric cases we must use the more general Metropolis-Hastings algorithm) and should be a close approximation to the posterior.  A common choice for the proposal is a multivariate normal with mean vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}_j$.

The Metropolis algorithm then proceeds as follows:

1. Choose an initial starting value $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$ for which the likelihood and priors are both positive
2. For $t \in \{1,2,3,...\}$ draw $\boldsymbol{\theta}_{*}$ from $J(\boldsymbol{\theta}_t\,|\,\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t-1})$ and calculate the ratio
   $$
   r=\frac{P(\boldsymbol{\theta}_{*}\,|\,y_1...y_n)}{P(\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t-1}\,|\,y_1...y_n)}=\frac{P(y_1...y_n\,|\,\boldsymbol{\theta}_{*})P(\boldsymbol{\theta}_{*})}{P(y_1...y_n\,|\,\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t-1})P(\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t-1})}
   $$
3. Set
   $$
   \boldsymbol{\theta}_t = \left\{
        \begin{array}{lr}
         \boldsymbol{\theta}_{*} \;\;\mathrm{with\;\;probability}\;\;\min\{r,1\}\\
          \boldsymbol{\theta} \;\;\mathrm{otherwise}
        \end{array}
      \right.
   $$
   The sequence $\{\boldsymbol{\theta}_t\}$ converges in distribution to $P(\boldsymbol{\theta}\,|\,y_1...y_n)$.  This sequence forms the Monte Carlo sample discussed above which you can use to calculate the probabilities of hypotheses about $\boldsymbol{\theta}$.  There are many proofs available so instead of hacking up my own google "Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm".

Anyway that is a really long answer, but I hope it helps to answer your question.

Comment: +1 this is a good answer. One correction would be that you discuss MCMC in the context of Bayesian *inference*. To the best of my knowledge, MCMC deals only with Bayesian *estimation*, or how to obtain the actual pdf of the posterior. Inferece, in a Bayesian context, takes all of this one step further in terms of how one chooses to summarize uncertainty, and/or make conduct formal tests of hypotheses.

Comment: To be honest if I could, I would give you 100 points.

Comment: @AdamO: MCMC is formally _unrelated_ with Bayesian inference in that it is a Monte Carlo method to simulate from a given target. To wit, the very first MCMC algorithm by Metropolis et al. (1953) had nothing to do with Bayesian inference. From the 1990's, Bayesian inference benefited a lot from MCMC methods, to be sure, but MCMC is not restricted to this statistical practice.

Comment: I know that this answer is quite old but thank you very much for explaining this algorithm! I have lost count on the number of papers I've been through to attempt to understand this method. I like it how you 'state the obvious' at several points in your answer, as it is often the obvious that others don't understand first-time.

Answer (score 2):

If the data have a normal distribution, and you're estimating the mean, putting a mostly uninformative normal prior on the mean and inverse gaussian prior on the variance gives you a conjugate  prior. Many commonly estimated types of parameters have conjugate priors to simplify estimation... like a Bernoulli probability with a beta prior.

We are not bound by law to use conjugate  priors. They're not always available, and sometimes it's much easier to throw an "easy to digest" prior at everything rather than going through complex derivations. Easy to digest priors might include a Jeffrey's prior.

That introduces the other error. In Bayesian statistics, we know quite a bit about the parameter after data have been observed, we are not just using approximate confidence intervals to summarize our uncertainty, but we have a whole probability distribution for the posterior which needs to be estimated and described ... and done so reliably!

MCMC refers to any numerical routine, including direct integration, for obtaining the posterior density. The easiest routines to understand are rejection sampling or the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm. The most commonly used routine is Gibbs sampling. The routine is easy to understand, but somewhat techincal. You can read wiki and try it out in R with the mcmc package.

Comment: Thanks. But still I am not clear about estimating parameters in posterior. Maybe an example makes my life easier

Comment: @Hamed You are not estimating parameters in the posterior. You are estimating the posterior--full stop. You can present any number of summaries. The posterior mode, for instance, is a close analogue to the maximum likelihood estimator.

Comment: Thanks AdamO. But the how can I estimate posterior without estimating parameters of distribution?

Comment: @Hamed When you say "parameters of distribution" WHAT parameters are you referring to? You specify a prior, you create a probability model for the outcome that leads to a likelihood, taken together they create a posterior density. The posterior is usually not a recognizable distribution that *has* meaningful parameters... though you can summarize it with empirical estimates, like the mean (e.g. posterior mean).

Comment: Let me explain that with an example. Assume $y_i,i=1,\ldots,n$ follow a normal distribution, $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu\sim N(0,10)$ and $\sigma\sim e(2)$. Then posterior could be like $\prod_1^n f_{N(\mu,\sigma^2)}(y_i)* f_{N(0,10)}(\mu) *f_{e(2)}(\sigma^2)$. Then what is the next step?

Comment: @Hamed I presume in your example you've supplied conjugate priors to the model, so then you can algebraically come up with the parameters for the posterior and summarize the data's impact on your beliefs about $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ using the posterior's parameters (in this case because the posterior is a "known" density). If the posterior weren't known you could summarize a density of *any* shape using the mode, it's quantiles, or other measures of shape/spread.

Comment: thanks @AdamO. Can you please unhold this question? I see people who attempted to answer my question and it is not fair to put such a this question and very nice answers on hold.

Comment: @Hamed no. The SE network is clear on issues like this. You need to consult autodidactic materials. If, as you work through examples and come across more specific conceptual difficulties, you wish to ask more specific / answerable questions, this SE network is a fine place to field such questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should read **Doing Bayesian Data Analysis 2e** from John K. Kruschke:

https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/

It is easy to read, and easy to understand. In the **Bayes Rule** (chapter 4, page 106), you read:

$$\underbrace{p(\theta|D)}_{\large\text{posterior}} = \underbrace{p(D|\theta)}_{\large\text{likelihood}} \quad \underbrace{p(\theta)}_{\large\text{prior}} \; / \quad\underbrace{p(D)}_{\large\text{evidence}}$$

I am quoting from the same page:

> The "prior,", $p(\theta)$ is the credibity of the $\theta$ values
>   without the data $D$. The "posterior," $p(\theta|D)$ is the
>   credibility of $\theta$ values with the data $D$ taken into account.
>   The "likelihood," $p(D|\theta)$, is the probability that the data
>   could be generated by the model with parameter value $\theta$. The
>   "evidence" for the model, $p(D)$, is the overall proability of the
>   data according to the model, determined by averaging across all
>   possible parameter values weighted by the strength of belief in those
>   parameter values.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the equation more?

Comment: I have just added some explanation from the book. But if you want to do some serious work, you should read the book. You will also find description of MCMC and explanation of Jags and Stan and the way you can use them with R (or other famous statistical software you may know).